# Codeigniter query builder class results

Tags: php, codeigniter, query-builder

Is it safe to assume in codeigniter query builder class for every successful query it will automatically return true and false if it fails?

If so, does it apply to CRUD? or is it only true when inserting and deleting data? For updating would i have to check affected rows? or will it also return a true result if update was successful?

For example:

controller:

```
$data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username'),
    'password' => password_hash($this->input->post('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
    'date_created' => mdate('%Y-%m-%d', time())
);

$result = $this->account_model->create($data);

if($result == TRUE){
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Registration Successful');
    redirect('pages/login');
}else{
    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Registration Failed');
    redirect('pages/register');
}
```

model:

```
public function create($new_user){
    $insert = array('username' => $new_user['username'],
        'password' => $new_user['password'], 
        'date_created' => $new_user['date_created']
    );

    $result = $this->db->insert('user', $insert);

    return $result;

}
```

also, is it bad if i returned the query statement itself? like,

```
return $this->db->insert('user', $insert);
```

Comment: The Codeigniter Docu is pretty straight forward - Just take a look at e.g. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=insert#CI_DB_query_builder::insert - an insert statement always returns `true` or `false` the same applies for `update` - its probably up to you how you assess those specifications.

Comment: I tried to output the result of a query and it returned an object array.

Maybe because in php if($var), will be true if var isn't empty. 

It also doesnt specifically says in the userguide that a successful query returns true and false if not.

i tried looking for it with ctrl+f but i just couldnt find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not really.
You can, however, control what the model returns. Keep in mind that an empty resultset, for example, is not necessarily a "failed" query. There's a lot of use cases where an empty resultset may be a good thing.

After actually running the query you will get an object with the result

for instance, when selecting, you can do `$result = $this->db->get()` and your `$result` variable will become an object with a lot of information you can access:

Number of returned rows: `$result->num_rows();`
Returned contents: `$result->result();`
Specific rows: `$result->row(0);`
Specific field in a specific row: `$result->row(3)->field_name;`

When inserting or updating, `$this->db->affected_rows()` becomes available so you can check how many rows were updated or inserted. Inserts also make `$this->db->insert_id()` available in case you need the table's primary key value for the row you inserted.

Thus, you are in control of the logic.

when selecting, I usually do:

```
$query = $this->db->get();
if ($query->num_rows() == 0)
{
  return false;
}

else
{
  return $query->row(0);
}
```

Then I check, in the controller, if the model returned false or a real resultset (sometimes I just return `true` instead of the actual resultset if I'm just checking for something to exist). You can tailor the results to your needs.

When inserting, I usually check:

```
if ($this->db->affected_rows() != 0)
{
  return $this->db->insert_id();
}

else
{
  return false;
}
```

(in the controller, a `false` being returned would be handled as an "insertion failed").

To answer your question more globally: No, nothing really happens by default, but Codeigniter gives you everything you need to tailor the behavior of your site to your specific needs and tastes

Comment: For the affected rows, it only refers to the 'affected rows' from the query and not the database/table itself?

Comment: exactly... it's the number of rows affected by the update or insert query (the same output you'd see if you did the update/insert directly on the database... like `2 row(s) affected Rows matched: 2  Changed: 2  Warnings: 0`

Comment: A simple question: Would it be okay to use $result variable more than once in a single function? for example, $result = $this->db->insert('user',$new_user);
if($this->db->affected_rows() != 0){
$result = $this->db->insert('profile', $new_profile);
if($this->db->affected_rows() != 0){
return true;}}

Comment: nevermind, i didn't even need to assign the db insert to a variable because i only needed to know if it was a successful query or not.

Comment: @Awing it is possible because the variable will get overwritten by the new assignment as the script continues to execute. If you need to use that data later then I would suggest changing the variables further down to something else :)